# How to get data from iframes

Tags: c#, iframe, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

```
 <td>
   <iframe>
     #document
       <html>
         <body>
           <table>
             <tbody>
               <tr>..<tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>
<select id="selYear" onchange="document.getElementById('selCat').selectedIndex=0;  
document.g…tedIndex=0;document.getElementById('frmFindParts').submit();"
 name="year">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="2014"></option>
                   </td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
       </table><body></html></iframe></tr>
```

I need the data inside **option** value and output is **2014**.I am using c#. I need the xpath for this exactly.
**here is my code**

```
var html = PageRetriever.ReadFromServer(pqi.URL, false);
            var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
            var tags = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("Xpath please");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var options = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//option")
                .Select(o => o.Attributes["value"].Value)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: I want to loop all option values in a list using foreach loop.Here  firstoption value is null. Its raising an exception.How to avoid this

Comment: @user3487646  `options[1]` or `foreach (var option in options) Console.WriteLine(option);`

Comment: Still I am getting null value can u please check here is the exact website (http://www.partspros.com) I want to get dropdown list year values.

Comment: @user3487646 because there is no *option* in that page. Your url and the html in question are diffeent.

Comment: I posted half code the before this working (//body//table[1]//tr[3]//td[3]//table//tr//td//iframe)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way :

```
var result = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("//iframe//table//select[@id='selYear']/option[@value!='']")
                .Select(o => o.Attributes["value"].Value);
//this will print : 2014
foreach (string s in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Still I am getting null value can u please check here is the exact website http://www.partspros.com I want to get dropdown list year values.